# Where can I find some good information about how the new canvas HTML element works?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I keep reading about how great this new Canvas element for HTML5 is and I see amazing demos done with just javascript and no flash.  Where can I find some good information on how to some of these things myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#the-canvas-element) defines the API and behaviour.

[This tutorial](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) should help you get started.

Answer (score 1):

There's the original [Apple tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/Canvas.html)

Also the [draft html5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/html5/#the-canvas-element)

And of course you can (as people have) ask questions about specific features, etc on SO :D

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this HTML5 Canvas Cheat Sheet, it is thorough and easy to read.

http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2009/02/html5-canvas-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2009/06/29/game-development-with-javascript-and-the-canvas-element.aspx) is a 14 part series that shows you how to create a simple platform game using the canvas element.

Answer (score 0):

[Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/by/topic/canvas) has a great collection of articles / posts regarding new Canvas innovations and developments.  This can show you what others are already doing.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't super deep, but it is easy to read and gives great examples:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial

It is where I got my start (I now have a couple iOS apps out there using js + canvas)